# dbeaver connect TNS:destination host unreachable ca

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

Can connect to oracle database from Oracle SQL developer but cannot connect to sys as sysdb from command prompt[image]

I wanted to connect to oracle database using dbeaver. Facing an error[image]

Comment: Is `ORCL` the correct `SERVICE_NAME`? The error suggests that it is not.